# How to use an existing Putty-SSH-Connection with HttpClient

Tags: c#, ssh, port, socks, dotnet-httpclient

I have set up a *SSH* connection to a remote computer on a specific local port via *Putty*.
It works fine, as I can use it with Firefox, setting the *SOCKS-Host* on this port.

I want to use this connection with my program, where I use `HttpClient` to do the work (send data to DB).

Is there a way to access the port with `HttpClient`? Simply putting it into the address didn't work.

Tried to attend `WebProxy("127.0.0.1", port)` to the client, but it didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have set up a SOCKS proxy, not an HTTP proxy. I don't usually code C#, so I did a google search, but it is unclear to me whether `WebProxy` directly supports SOCKS proxies - to me it seems SOCKS support is lacking in .NET, unless you can find some freely available, third party classes.

You can look into using a SOCKS proxy with `WebProxy` - you can probably achieve the same thing using some wrapper class. Another option is set up *Polipo* or *Privoxy*, and then use your existing code changing only the port for your `WebProxy` call. They are both HTTP proxies that feature proxy chaining with existing SOCKS proxies - configure to use your SSH SOCKS proxy, and you're good to go...